# Angular Dynamic Forms - adding remote source via http.get request

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms

I'm currently working on a dynamic form project, I've used the following code as a starting point - [Building Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) which works great out of the box.

However I've seem to hit a problem when I want to dynamically create the form fields based on JSON being passed in.

I understand that when I use a http.get(), this return an observable, but the variable from the dynamic forms code is also a observable `const questions: QuestionBase<string>[]`, so I need to map it some how?

The code below is from the question service works fine because its hard coded:

```js
getQuestions() {

const questions: QuestionBase<string>[] = [

  new DropdownQuestion({
    key: 'brave',
    label: 'Bravery Rating',
    options: [
      {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
      {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
      {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
      {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
    ],
    order: 3
  }),

  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'firstName',
    label: 'First name',
    value: 'Bombasto',
    required: true,
    order: 1
  }),

  new TextboxQuestion({
    key: 'emailAddress',
    label: 'Email',
    type: 'email',
    order: 2
  })
];

return of(questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)); }
```

This is my code to dynamically create the form fields:

```js
getQuestions(id:any) {

const questions: QuestionBase<string>[] = [];

// Dynamically create form fields
this.dataService.loaddatafromJSON() // This is just an http.get request
.subscribe((response) => {
  if (response != null)
  {
    var form = response.forms.filter(x => x.id === id); // Get form from custom object array
    var fields = form.fields; // Get all fields from Form e.g. textbox, textarea etc...

    for (var field of fields) { // Interate through form fields
      if (field.type === "textbox")
      {
        // Found Textbox field, add to question array and so on...
        questions.push(
          new TextboxQuestion({
            key: 'id',
            label: 'label',
            value: '',
            required: true,
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            order: 1
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }
});
// ------------------------------

return of(questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)); }
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'id'
at _throwError (forms.js:2431)
at setUpControl (forms.js:2337)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5475)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6057)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5988)
at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:2131)
at callHook (core.js:3042)
at callHooks (core.js:3008)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
at refreshView (core.js:7187)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I just want to be able to rebuild the Question array and return.

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am having a similar issue, the controls won't load properly either like you list or with the isValid function in the ts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this, in dynamic-form.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I probably describe this poorly as I am new to this as well, but I had the same problem. The method **getQuestions()** from the Angular tutorial (your first snippet above) returns an **Observable** through the last line

```
'return of(...)'.
```

If you want this function to return data from a server query, then you need to make sure, that your method still returns an **Observable**. It could look a bit like this...sorry for not taking your example into account but you might get the point...you **return a http request (but not subscribing to it)**:

```
    getQuestions() {
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        };

        const url = 'http://...';
        const body = ...;

        return this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            map(dataRaw => this.createQuestions(dataRaw))
          );
      }
      

    createQuestions(dataRaw: any) {
        let questions: QuestionBase<string>[] = [];

        dataRaw.forEach(question=> {
          questions.push(new TextboxQuestion(question));
        });

        return questions;
      }
```